# C# Remove item from nested dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested

I've got a simple question that my mind is drawing a blank to: I have a Dictionary that looks something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict;
```

As far as I know, dict.Remove() would remove any entry by key, but I need to only remove an item from the innermost dictionary. How would I go about that?

Comment: Get the inner dictionary and call `Remove()` on that.  I.e., get the value specified by the key in the parent dictionary.

Comment: Nested dictionary is a smell. Use appropriate data structure. It could be Dictionary of some class which in turn has a dictionary. Not nested dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well presumably you've got two keys: one for the outer dictionary and one for the nested one.

So assuming you know that the entry is present, you can use

```
dict[outerKey].Remove(innerKey);
```

If you don't know whether the entry exists, you want something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> innerDict;
if (dict.TryGetValue(outerKey, out innerDict))
{
    // It doesn't matter whether or not innerKey exists beforehand
    innerDict.Remove(innerKey);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just have the inner key, you can do something like this:

```
string removeKey = "42";

Dictionary<String, String> removeDict = dict.Select(d=> d.Value).FirstOrDefault(d => d.ContainsKey(removeKey));

if(removeDict !=null)  
    removeDict.Remove(removeKey);
```

In this implementation if there is more then one register with the same innerKey just the first occurrence will be removed

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dict["key"].Remove("childkey");
```

Notice the keys are string values.